# Cast from 'UIViewController' to unrelated type 'TableViewCell' always fails

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, casting

I got this error "Cast from 'UIViewController' to unrelated type 'TableViewCell' always fails"

I am trying to manipulate the outlets in my TableViewCell controller. So I want to cast some data from UIViewController to UITableViewCell.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1VmS.png)

Comment: Can you show the code where you get the error?

Comment: @Paulw11 did you happen to check the attached image?

Comment: No, I didn't notice that, but you should always include the relevant code in your question rather than including it in an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-[UIStoryboardSegue destinationViewController]` returns a `UIViewController*`. Assuming `TableViewCell` is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, the cast does not make sense. From the information I see, you'll want to check if the `destinationViewController` points to an instance of `UITableViewController` and then cast it.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController];
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewControler class]])
{
    UITableViewController *tableViewController = (UITableViewController *) viewController;
}
```

From there, you can access the cells using any of `UITableViewController`'s methods, probably those that implement `UITableViewDelegate` or `UITableViewDataSource`. If you require more implementation specific control you can cast to `TableVC` after checking that `destinationViewController` is an instance of that class.